# Why is gcc not showing a warning message for using $ in a variable name?

Tags: c, gcc, gcc-warning

I'm new to C and am learning C from *Programming in C*, 4th ed. by Stephen Kochan. On page 29, he writes `$` is not a valid character for variable names. He is using the C11 standard.

I wrote the following code

```
#include <stdio.h>

int main (void)
{
    int a$ = 1;

    printf ("%i", a$);

    return 0;
}
```

and ran it with the command `gcc -std=c11 -pedantic practice.c -o practice.o && ./practice.o`. My filename is `practice.c`.

The output is `1`. Shouldn't the compiler give me a warning for using `$`? Isn't using `$` sign for identifiers an extension that GCC provides?

I'm using GCC 8.2.0 in Ubuntu 18.10.

Edit:

Also, doesn't GCC not use the GNU extensions when I use `-std=c11`? That is what is written in the Appendix of the book (pg. no. 497).

I am getting an warning by using `-std=c89` though.

Comment: It is valid, but not recommended, for readability sake...

Comment: Unrelated, but the `.o` extension is usually used for object files, not for the final executable.

Comment: @FedericoklezCulloca Can I ask what is the extension of the final executable? When I remove `.o` the file still gets compiled. There is a file named `practice` in my directory. What is its extension? Its properties show type as "shared library".

Comment: There's no extension for executables in *nix systems. The filesystem doesn't use that to determine the type of a file. So usually executables just don't have extensions and `practice` is correct. Check your `/usr/bin` directory and you'll see that the programs there don't have an extension either.

Comment: About the fact that its properties say "shared library" is probably because of your desktop environment. If I do `file practice` from the command line I get `practice: ELF 64-bit LSB shared object, x86-64, version 1 (SYSV), dynamically linked, interpreter /lib64/ld-linux-x86-64.so.2, for GNU/Linux 2.6.32, BuildID[sha1]=928002f23b27d5c9bc55a15bf769edfaf3e62c23, not stripped`

Comment: @FedericoklezCulloca Thanks for the information. I also get the same result from the command line although I do not understand it at all.

Comment: Wait, a `$` suffix for an _integer_? Nooooooo....

Comment: The `file` utility can show `shared object` for an ELF executable if it is a [position-independent executable](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Position-independent_code#Position-independent_executables). Some distributions configure GCC so that it creates position-independent executables by default (usually this requires using `-pie` and `-fPIC` options).

Comment: @MrLister: Although traditional BASIC implementations used $ as a suffix for string-variable names, I wouldn't expect a trailing $ to have similar meanings in C.  If I was examining code that used such a suffix, I'd expect that the programmer was exploiting some special way that the target implementation would process identifiers with such a suffix.  For example, a compiler targeting a platform which can access objects near the frame pointer faster than those which are further away might place all objects whose names have a trailing `$` after those that don't.

Comment: @supercat You put much more thought in that remark than my comment deserved, for which I have to apologise.

Comment: @MrLister: No apology needed.  My main point was that programmers who use `$` in identifiers generally do so because something about their intended target makes it necessary.  I've not seen any implementations that attached meanings to automatic-duration identifiers, but found it interesting to think back over my 20+ years of experience for places where such a form could have been (or could still be) useful.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

You get a warning with `-std=c89 -pedantic`. C99 and later allow [other implementation-defined characters](http://port70.net/~nsz/c/c99/n1256.html#6.4.2) in identifiers.

Comment: Yes. This is the reference: https://gcc.gnu.org/onlinedocs/gcc-8.2.0/cpp/Implementation-defined-behavior.html#Implementation-defined-behavior

Answer (score 2):

According to this : [GCC Documentation](http://gcc.gnu.org/onlinedocs/gcc/Dollar-Signs.html#Dollar-Signs)

> In GNU C, you may normally use dollar signs in identifier names. This
>   is because many traditional C implementations allow such identifiers.
>   However, dollar signs in identifiers are not supported on a few target
>   machines, typically because the target assembler does not allow them.

So, `$` is valid, but it's not a conforming way to code in C.

Comment: It's not valid C, only on GCC C. Try compiling with -ansi or -std=C11 and the warnings will start appearing.

Comment: @Spidey with `-std=c11` no warning appears

Comment: @Spidey nope, still no warnings.

Comment: @Spidey: The Standard has no definition for "valid C".  Its definition for a "conforming C program" encompasses any blob of text that is acceptable to at least one conforming C implementation.  A source text that uses dollar signs in identifiers could not be a "strictly conforming proogram", but the authors of the Standard recognize that much C's usefulness stems from the ability to write non-portable programs that will be usefully processed by some C implementations even if not by all of them.